# How to create a public accessible folder in react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using [React Boilerplate](https://www.reactboilerplate.com/). I am running that project on my localhost. So I have a folder "ankur" outside "app" directory.
[check out folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlb83.png). How can I access that folder via link? (ex: localhost:3000/ankur)?

If required I can move the folder.

I have no knowledge in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the react boilerplate provided by Facebook [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Once you're done with the setup, your directory should look like this:

```
 my-app
 ├── README.md
 ├── node_modules
 ├── package.json
 ├── .gitignore
 ├── public
 │   ├── favicon.ico
 │   ├── index.html
 │   └── manifest.json
 └── src
     ├── App.css
     ├── App.js
     ├── App.test.js
     ├── index.css
     ├── index.js
     ├── logo.svg
     └── registerServiceWorker.js
```

Then, just put your folder/files that you want to be accessible in the `public` folder. In your case, just put `ankur` folder inside public folder and access it through `localhost:3000/ankur`

Comment: Already I have started this project using React Boilerplate. So I right now I can't switch back.